# Sharepoint 2013 'Change Query' button does not work in Content Search Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-query-web-part, content-search-web-part

I'm trying to change the result source of Content Search Web Part, but when i click on the button 'Change Query', in web part properties, the page postback and the dialog does not showing up.
In browser console, i can see the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'QueryBuilder' of undefined
at Array.Search_Configuration_QueryBuilder$onLoad (http://mySite:8080/_layouts/15/search.configuration.debug.js?rev=zldCOhFvrMg2hZjkCGfP5A%3D%3D:1080:94)
at http://mySite:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=roPHFDHMPE9qkAB7z_cY9vEvqXQ…wiWtps7ch8yBvO8RGXGUQqWQNDMpnSavOQMlmWinBGQOtw0&t=ffffffffeea0dba9:3484:23
at Sys$_Application$raiseLoad [as raiseLoad] (http://mySite:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=roPHFDHMPE9qkAB7z_cY9vEvqXQ…wiWtps7ch8yBvO8RGXGUQqWQNDMpnSavOQMlmWinBGQOtw0&t=ffffffffeea0dba9:4978:13)
at Sys$_Application$initialize [as initialize] (http://mySite:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=roPHFDHMPE9qkAB7z_cY9vEvqXQ…wiWtps7ch8yBvO8RGXGUQqWQNDMpnSavOQMlmWinBGQOtw0&t=ffffffffeea0dba9:4950:18)
at init (http://mySite:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=roPHFDHMPE9qkAB7z_cY9vEvqXQ…wiWtps7ch8yBvO8RGXGUQqWQNDMpnSavOQMlmWinBGQOtw0&t=ffffffffeea0dba9:5038:31)
at HTMLDocument.check (http://mySite:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=roPHFDHMPE9qkAB7z_cY9vEvqXQ…wiWtps7ch8yBvO8RGXGUQqWQNDMpnSavOQMlmWinBGQOtw0&t=ffffffffeea0dba9:5049:21)
```

I tried to add the reference to sp.dialog.js in master page, but it does not change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just try to add content search webpart in another page, may be some other js code is conflicting....

Comment: I tried to change Page Layout and i noticed that proabably, some js is conflicting with code.. I can't figured out what of this...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a E3 (or higher) subscription plan, you can't change the query of the CSWP. Check your subscription in the Admin Center.

Comment: Now I have 'SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License' subscription type.

Comment: And you're having at least design permission level?

Comment: Of course, I'm having a full-control

Comment: I really can't figured out....

Comment: I even tried to change the master page and assign it the standard 'Oslo', but it doesn't matter...

Comment: Strange. Does this give any insight? http://www.maadarani.com/missing-content-search-web-part/

Comment: None... the spule is disabled...this is very strange because in CA, QueryBuilder works, when i'm creating a new result source and test the query.

Comment: Ok I found that the problem is the custom web part zone. Now I have to understand why...

Comment: @Jay LOL! Well, I hope you find the error, cause I'm deleting my wrong answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I had a separate JS script in the page where the Search results web part was present.

The code looked like this

```
//function Search(queryText) {
//    var d = $.Deferred();
//
//    SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
//        SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Search.js", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery", function () {
//            var sContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
//            var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(sContext);
//            keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
//            keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryText);
//            var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(sContext);
//            results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
//            sContext.executeQueryAsync(
//                function () {
//                    d.resolve(results);
//                },
//                function (err) {
//                    d.reject(err);
//                }
//            );
//        });
//    });
//
//    return d.promise();
//}
//
//function SearchBind(){
//  $('#SearchButton').click(function(event){
//      event.preventDefault();
//      var searchText=$('#SearchInput').val();
//      Search(searchText).done(function(results){
//          console.log(results);
//      })
//      .fail(function(error){
//          console.log(error);
//      });
//  }); // close click
//}
```

After I commented it , The Change Query dialog box worked again.

I think the SOD loading of `SP.Search.js` again messed up the Query object. Like how loading jQuery twice in the same page unbinds all events from the first jQuery Object.